# How to be sure that the process is set to REAL_TIME priority

Tags: c++, process, real-time, win32-process

I'm developing a console C++ application with Visual Studio on Windows XP that must be at the highest priority possible for the scheduler.

```
 int main()
 {
     while ( somecondition )
     {
        // pick data from external hardware every 10 milliseconds
        // do computation 
     }

 }
```

I mean no other system process should interfere with it because it's a real time data acquisition system tuned to refresh the frame buffer every 10 milliseconds.

I tried to save to a file the temporal length of each frame and I found a strange "quantization" around my desidered time. Why?

I also found that sometimes the length is a multiple of my base frame time, is this caused by interfering internal O.S. processes?

Is there a way to ensure the highest priority of my program?

Comment: Keep in mind several things.  First, Windows XP offers no real time guarantees, even for "real time" priority, so you can't theorically achieve what you want (in practice, your mileage may vary).  Second, writing to a file introduces a *huge* bias in your measurements.  It might just be that the "quantization" you see is actually caused by the I/O system.

Comment: so what should be the method to measure timing in this case?

appending the delta t to a list and when the program is finished, flushing it?

Comment: That will likely introduce a smaller (and more predictable) bias, especially if the list is pre-allocated.  You can flush it at regular intervals too, and this will probably even allow you to measure the file bias.  There are techniques to measure the bias itself, if you prefer (although that won't help you keep your 10ms time frame).

Comment: It's usual to use a driver and associated buffers and signaling for such operations.  How does your hardware interface work?  Video I/O is a usually tradeoff between latency and frame-rate - a high frame-rate is difficult to maintain without a lot of 'slack' - drivers, threads and queues of frame buffers.  Disk writing the same - writing the files in 'real-time' with no queueing/latency is often not possible, especially with rotating media.

Comment: my hardware interface is a PCI card which communicates with a infrared tracking system while my program is written in Glut and need to save on hard drive information of markers positions at every frame.

Comment: How do you communicate with the driver?  Typical audio/video interfaces work by supplying the drive with a pool of frame buffers and the driver signals when a buffer is full.  The app code can then queue up the buffers and write them to the file/s asynchronously.  Video bandwidth and disk latency tend to defeat any simple approach that avoids queueing frame buffers.  A typical frame buffer every 10ms is not such a huge load overall on todays hardware, but there will be latency that must be accommodated.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is to call [SetThreadPriority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686277%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I used like this:

```
HANDLE hThread = GetCurrentThread(void);
SetThreadPriority(hThread, THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL);
```

Just to to note that other application can do same, so both threads will have same priority.

Comment: How about mixing boost::thread with win32 api calls to GetCurrentThread and SetThreadPriority?

Comment: Boost implementation on windows will call the same code.You can check boost source code.